# Searching for a string in HashSet<string> Performance

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a `HashSet<string>` with ~50k members.  I have another list of objects that I'm iterating through one by one to determine if the object's email exists.  If it does, I need to perform some action on the object.

```
var emailList = db.Emails.Select(s => s.EmailAddress.ToLower()).ToList();
var emailHash = new HashSet<string>(emailList);
var objects = db.Objects.ToList();
// everything is fine up to this point
foreach (var object in objects) {
   if (!emailHash.Any(s => s.Equals(object.Email))) { // This takes ~0.3s
      Console.WriteLine("Email: {0}", object.Email);     
   }
}
```

What can I do to speed up the evaluation of whether or not one string exists in a list of strings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not using the HashSet correctly. Using Linq's `.Any()` will actually evaluate your condition against each element stored in the HashSet.

To search if an item exists in a HashSet (with constant time, `O(1)`) use `emailHash.Contains(object.Email)`.

Answer (score 4):

One obvious change is to **not** use the `Enumerable.Any()` LINQ function, which basically negates the advantages of using a hash set by performing a sequential search.

Instead, use HashSet's built-in `Contains(string)` function:

```
foreach (var object in objects) {
   if (!emailHash.Contains(object.Email)) {
      Console.WriteLine("Email: {0}", object.Email);     
   }
}
```